# Relationships: Show other fields in list for Relationship field when creating an entry

Tags: channel-entries, relationships

When creating entries, is there any way to configure a Relationship field, so that in the list displayed on the entry form, you see more than just the data from the Title field? Could I have it include data from other fields, especially custom fields?

Background:
I have a channel called "Portfolios" which has a Relationship field called "Site Projects." My site works such that a client can enter a bunch of entries in the Projects channel, then create Portfolio entries where they can pick multiple Projects in the Relationship field (Site Projects) to be displayed in a list on the main website.

The problem is that the client entered all the data and there are TONS of entries in the Projects channel. So many that it's hard to tell much about them merely from their titles. They asked if I could set EE up so that when they are entering Portfolio entries, the list for the Relationship field of Site Projects would show data from another custom field or two, as well (like "Project ID" and or "Launch Date") so they know exactly what they are selecting.

Comment: Nothing I'm aware of apart from hacking the ExpressionEngine core files.

Comment: Nuts. I wonder if Playa would do it. The screenshot on this page seems to indicate you can filter entries by "keywords" in the publish/edit form, but I don't know what that means, exactly. (Custom field data included?) http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa

Comment: Tech support at Playa confirmed for me that this does *not* work as I hoped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I used the Title Master add-on (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/title-master) - and basically created an entry title that had more info in it (channel name in my case due to multiple channels with like-named entries).

I wouldn't use Title Master at the moment as it doesn't look to be keeping up with EE well, but possibly the approach could be done using MS Title Control instead: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-title-control.

Comment: Very interesting. Not sure if I can make this work. The titles would be forever long: Normal title info + Launch Date + unpredictable number of comma separated project ID numbers from that custom ID field. I reckon I'd have to do a ton of regex or string parsing on the web site to display info the way I'm currently displaying it. Might run up against a max length in the title field?

Comment: Read up on it more. This appears to be my best shot and might not require the heavy lifting I thought. Thanks.